# about caffe python API

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I am using caffe for deep learning and want to make a python softmaxwithloss layer(maybe doesn't make sense but I wanna try). The problem is my layer does not work at the backward section in training phase(got NANs in data).

Question is: how caffe backward work for training? Does every layer learning its diff (caffe.Layer[0].diff or something similar) and convey it to next layer? So the only thing to do is calculate every bottom layer's diff that can make backward work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can read and find more information about the anatomy of Caffe model [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html).

this is another [tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html) on Caffe technology : basic commands, Python and C++ code.